# Email Form - Not Sending the Email Correctly

Tags: html, forms, email

This is the form I am using:

```html
<form action="mailto:heroicostrich@gmail.com" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="EmailTestForm">
  <div id="contentform">
    Your Name:
    <br>
    <input type="text" size="20" name="VisitorName">
    <br>
    <br>Your Comment:
    <br>
    <textarea name="VisitorComment" rows="4" cols="20">
    </textarea>
    <br>
    <br>

    <input type="submit" value="Email This Form">
  </div>
</form>
```

However, I have 2 issues.

1. When I click the "Email This Form" button with the information filled out, nothing happens in Google Chrome. I looked that up and saw many posts on how it doesn't work in Chrome, but no solution.
2. In other browsers that work, such as Internet Explorer, clicking the button results in this message: "This form is being submitted using e-mail. Submitting this form will reveal your e-mail address to the recipient, and will send the form data without encrypting it for privacy. You may continue or cancel this submission". Clicking OK links you to google.com and just sits there, not sending the email.

Comment: Using the mailto: action depends on how the client is configured. There's also no need for a method since you're not sending this to be processed by a script.

Comment: @j08691 is there an alternative to using mail:to then?